# ActionScript Access to symbol isn't working

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I am using ActionScript 2.0, but I think in this case the difference is small.
I have created a scene with a symbol inside which there is a timeline and export it for actionscript with class name "def". I want to play sound only on specific frames of "def", but it continues to plays on other frames.

My code:

```
soundsamp = new Sound(this);  
soundsamp.attachSound("soundsamp.wav");  
soundsamp.start();  
soundsamp.onSoundComplete = function(){
    if (def._currentframe <= 8){
        soundsamp.start();
    } 
}  
    if (def._currentframe > 8){
        soundsamp.stop();
}
```

Why it is not working?

[symbol on timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvaUe.png)

Comment: Probably because "def" has no meaning other than **linkage name** and does not refer to that MovieClip instance. Hence, **def._currentframe** is always **undefined** which is probably 0 if you compare it to a number.

Comment: I think your best shot is to use the **_global** context (it is a predefined object visible from everywhere). So in the first frame of that "def" MovieClip you "broadcast" it like **_global.def = this;** so then everywhere else you can address it as **_global.def**, thus **_global.def._currentframe** would be correct.